# Getting oauth token using Jmeter xpath extractor and using it in path of other Http Request

Tags: jmeter

What should be the Regular expression if I want to extract the value for access token, So that i can use it in Path of other Http request ie like access_token=93ee29b4-74dc-4uu7-8e10-6eac6845511b  from below http response.

```
{
   "access_token":"93ee2tum-1234-56789-8e10-6eac684551tum",
   "token_type":"Bearer",
   "expires_in":3600,
   "scope":"test"
}
```

I have given regular expression as

> "access_token":"([^"]+)"

And also where can i check the value of regular expression I am getting

Answer (score 1):

You can test your Regular Expressions using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener in RegExp Tester mode like:

[image: View Results Tree]

Also you can use [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) to see the associated JMeter Variables. See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for details.

---

Starting from JMeter 3.0 it's more handy to use [JSON Path PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Path_PostProcessor), in that case the relevant [JSON Path](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) Expression would be as simple as:

```
$.access_token
```

[image: JSON Path PostProcessor]

Comment: But am not able to get the value ie 93ee2tum-1234-56789-8e10-6eac684551tum from regular expression

Comment: This Regular expression is not working.Since in RegExp Tester it showing (Match count: 0). Please can you suggest some other Regular Expression

Comment: When it comes to JSON data Regular Expressions may be fragile, you need to mind whitespaces, line breaks, any other formatting, etc. I cannot suggest anything valuable till I see **exact** response from the server. So I would recommend going for JSON Path PostProcessor or [JSON Path Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter) if you have to use JMeter < 3.0

Answer (score 0):

You can add following [regex](https://regex101.com/r/fB1aS6/1). It will get the token and depending on the name variable you set, you can add one [BeanShell Post-processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) to print the token in console for you to verify. Just add the following to it:

```
log.info(vars.get("token")); 
// token is the variable name which you specify in Regular Expression Extractor.
```